# How to create Composite Object?

Tags: objects

I'm fairly new to blender (2.8), been using it for just about a month now.

How do you combine a bunch of different objects (e.g. light, mesh, etc) to act as one object? That is so I can easily duplicate and edit the resulting composite object.

I've already checked collections, appears to be not I need. Already did some googling but I guess I'm in the wrong rabbit hole.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can't make objects of different types into a single object, but you can **make a group of "siblings" (children of an *Empty*) and duplicate them all together**. This method doesn't create instances but whole new objects: they will still be editable individually (at the cost of being all simultaneously in memory).

1. Add an Empty

   [image]
2. Select all the objects and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Select the *Empty*. Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and *Set Parent to Object*

   [image]
3. Duplicate the bunch (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) and *Move* (or rotate, or scale) the new Empty. Indeed, the duplication is smart enough to transfer the "Parent" relation to the new Empty

   [image]

You can select a group (for example if you need to delete it or duplicate further) by selecting the Empty, then doing *Select > Select More/Less > Extend Child* or just <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Nicola Sap proposed a solution (parent all your object to an empty), note that if you use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> instead of <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, your object copies will be linked, meaning if you change one object it will affect its copies.

Another solution could be Collection Instance:

Put your objects in the same collection (let say Collection1), then create an instance of this collection with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Collection Instance* > *Collection1*. You can move, rotate or scale the instance, but only the original objects will be editable.

Comment: Collection Instance does solve my current problem. So thanks.

To expand the solution, the instance/Duplicate can be made into real objects if you so desire by **ctrl** **A** > _Make Duplicates Real_